# Getting a version of a Conda package which has a specific dependency

Tags: python, matplotlib, pycharm

I ran into problems with `matplotlib` version 3.0.2 in the pycharm console. In my case `matplotlib` is installed as a dependency to `geopandas` (meaning that geopandas is really the thing I am installing in the first place).

According to [this link](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360000108710-Matplotlib-support-failed) the problem may go away if I revert my `matplotlib` revision to 2.1.2. However I'm a bit nervous doing this since it might mess with the original `geopandas` installation.

How can I seek out a revision of `geopandas` that uses my revision of choice for `matplotlib`? How do I downgrade my `geopandas` installation accordingly?

Comment: I don't think geopandas has a very hard limit on the exact matplotlib version is needs. I would install the matplotlib version you want to have, then try if geopandas still works as expected. If not, move to an earlier geopandas version iteratively until it works again. Note that the initial problem is really a problem of pycharm so consider not using pycharm or check if they have by now fixed their bug.

Comment: Consider using a virtual environment or a conda environment. That way if you screw up, just delete it and start again. No need to mess up your system wide Python environment.

Comment: Since you are using conda, you can clone the existing environment and play around with that.

Comment: I am not using the base environment (rarely do) so rest assured.  @ImportanceOfBeingEarnest It is highly unfortunate, but you may be right. I am definitely not a fan of spyders interface (Pycharms debugging features and ability to interact with version control, etc is far superior), but it might be less limiting since I work with anaconda to manage environments. It would be really good if Anaconda and Pycharm companies joined forces to make one killer python IDE with anaconda support.... only in my dreams...

Comment: I am using Pycharm with Anaconda on both Mac and Windows. Yes, Pycharm is great for most stuff except for Jupyter notebooks. I usually manage my Conda environments from the command line rather than within PyCharm itself. I am not sure what they do but even though PyCharm realizes it is a conda environment, the package dependency isn't managed too well.

Comment: I also manage my conda environments from the command line. Pycharm is also not that good with conda environments as this question (and many others) illustrates